# Is the strptime method in Python a method inside a method?

Tags: python

Why do we need to write datetime.datetime.strptime and not datetime.strptime to use  the strptime method ? Is it a method inside a method ?

Comment: it's a method of datetime.datetime https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Are all classes written in this format class.class ?

Comment: or is it like, a sub class of a class ?

Comment: it's about the person who design to put which the method it's in, @tdelaney explained it pretty well

Comment: it's a `method` also called a `function` in a class, it's listed in the docs

Answer (score 0):

`strptime` is a factory function that returns a `datetime.datetime` object. The author had the choice of putting it at the module level but decided to add namespace encapsulation because the call does not relate to the other classes in the module. This is a coding philosophy and is not required. But it is nice to have type hints. For instance, I may have implemented it at module level so that it is easy to spot in the `help` text but called it `datetime_from_strptime`.

To expand on the name, the authors wrote the module `datetime.py` and chose to implement a `class datetime`, so you get that odd `datetime.datetime` thing. Normal python coding standards would say that the class be `class DateTime` so that this odd looking stuff doesn't happen. But it remains `datetime` for historical reasons and because enough people find is visually pleasing.

**EDIT**

Because `strptime` is a class method, it has one nice feature over just defining a function a module level. Suppose I subclass `datetime`. `strptime` will construct my class instead of `datetime`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> class MyDateTime(datetime.datetime):
...     pass
... 
>>> dt = MyDateTime.strptime("30 Nov 00", "%d %b %y")
>>> type(dt)
<class '__main__.MyDateTime'>
```

This is great if my class's `__init__` is like `datetime` but a disaster if the reason why I subclassed was so that I could override `__init__`.

Comment: oh i see. i forgot that datetime is a module. So basically a module is a group of classes ? and datetime is a class in the module datetime ? so thats why we write datetime.datetime ? and datetime.datetime.strptime is a method of the class datetime of the module datetime ? did i understand correctly ?

Comment: @Aka895862 - yep, that's it. You can `print(datetime.__file__)` to get the path to `datetime.py` and look through it yourself. Search for `strptime` and you'll see that its a `@classmethod` on `class datetime`.

Comment: it got me confused. Thanks a lot for your answer !